# finding Peaks in image Histogram

Tags: c#, image-processing, histogram

I am witting a project of image processing.
For some part of my project to find good threshold value I need to find peaks and valleys of image's histogram.
I am witting my project in C# .net 
but I need Algorithm or sample code in any languages like(Java, C,C++,....) to understand the logic of that. I can convert to C# by my self.
any document or algorithm or piece of code...
thanks

Comment: Can you please show example of histogram?

Comment: You can make a Histogram with any data series. Perhaps you are thinking about a particular histogram derived from your images. Which one?

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to beat [Ohtsu's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) for binary thresholding.  Even if you insist on implementing local extrema searching by yourself, Ohtsu's method will give you a good result to compare to.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have computed your histogram, to find peaks and valleys is computationally trivial (loop over it and find local extrema). What is not trivial is to find "good" peaks and valleys to do some segmentation/threshold. But that is not a matter of coding, it's a matter of modelling. You can [google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=image+segmentation+threshold+histogram) for it.

If you want a simple recipe, and if you know that your histogram has "essentially" two peaks and a valley in the middle ("bimodal" histogram) and you want to locate that valley, I have once implemented the following ad-hoc procedure, with relative success:

- Compute all the extrema of the histogram (relative maxima/minima, including borders)
- If there are only two maxima, AND if in between those maxima there is only one local minimum, we've found the valley. Return it.
- Else, smooth the histogram (eg. a moving average) and go to first step.

Comment: I really cant understand how I have to find the second peak because the second max is not the second peak and we have so many small small peak that we don't want them. I google that but I couldn't find any thing about algorithm or code of that.

Comment: The "small peaks" disappear with the smoothing. In this approach, you smooth the histogram until there are only two peaks (maxima).